# How to view JSON file with all results from an Elastic Search?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Sorry, I've never used Elastic Search before and am a little confused here.

I've been given a site with Elastic Search on it. I want to download a .json file with all my results. These files area located on an AWS server and I can access the results by using a URL such as:

```
https://idnumbers.ap-southeast-2.aws.found.io/elasticsearch_products/_search
```

However, these seem to only show a very limited number of results, when in fact I know there should be thousands.

Is there a way for me to view the complete file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, only 10 results are coming back. You can add a `size=xyz` parameter to your URL in order to see more. This will get you 1000 results:

```
https://idnumbers.ap-southeast-2.aws.found.io/elasticsearch_products/_search?size=1000
```

However, there is a logical limit of how many results you can get back that way, which is [set at 10000](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html). So if you need to retrieve more results, you can look into the [scan/scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) which allows you to iterate over all your data set.

If you don't want to mess with those multiple queries, you can use [another tool](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump) which will do it for you and download the full content of your ES cluster into a file containing the JSON documents:

```
elasticdump \
  --input=https://idnumbers.ap-southeast-2.aws.found.io \
  --output=/tmp/idnumbers.json \
  --type=data
```