# How to save data of elasticsearch in format of json?

Tags: c++, c, json, file, elasticsearch

I want to get document from elasticsearch and save it in format of json. This I need in my c++ code.Searching in the web I have found a command:

> curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/

But I need to get data in json format, store it and then work with it in my c++ code.

I think I must use curl.h library.

But this is all that I know.
How can I do it?

Comment: Elasticdump is the solution here. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40778254/4604579

Comment: @Val it is using another tool to get it. I want to use c++ commands to get it.

Comment: How about using the `system()` call in C++ to run the `elasticdump` command?

Comment: @Val elasticdump is a command of this tool(https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump). I do not want to use this tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a C++ Elastic client, like [this one](https://seznam.github.io/elasticlient/).

You can then retrieve all your data in JSON by leveraging the [scroll API](https://seznam.github.io/elasticlient/classelasticlient_1_1Scroll.html). Sample usage can be found [here](https://github.com/seznam/elasticlient#usage-of-scroll-api)

Comment: Thanks for help.But is it store data on disk in json format?